# Integration fabricjs with requirejs

Tags: requirejs, fabricjs

I want to use `fabricjs` with require. I have other projects where i'm using `requirejs` so everything is configured right.
`fabricjs` is build with require support. I'm not clear why in dist file i have generated `fabric.require.js` and `fabric.js` but i tested all and not work.

Sample code (essential part):

```js
define(['fabric','jquery'], function (fabric,$) { 
  function Graph(config) {
   
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mycanvas');
    
    var circle = new fabric.Circle({
   radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100
    });
    
  }
  
  return Graph;
});
```

When i try to run this i got error: `fabric.Canvas` is not a function.
What is strange, when comment line where `fabric.Canvas` is invoked, code run without error so it's like `fabric.Circle` call is ok.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. When i build fabric, need to add and interaction module, so right command was:

node build.js requirejs modules=interaction

Now error was gone!